# Is this recursive?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Second attempt here, I just wanted to know if this is considered a recursive function.

The purpose of the function is to take a string and 
if the the first element is equal to the last element 
then append the last element to a list and return nothing,
else call istelf and pass the same string from index [1]
finally append the first element to the list

I know that error checking needs to be done on the if statement. However I am only doing this to try and get my head around recursion...Struggling to be honest.

Also I would never write a program like this if it where anything but trivial I just wanted to check if my understanding is correct so far.

```
def parse(theList):
    theList.reverse()
    parsedString = ''.join(theList)
    return parsedString




def recursiveMessage(theString):

    lastElement = theString[len(theString) - 1]

    if theString[0] == lastElement:
        buildString.append(theString[0])
        return None
    else:
        recursiveMessage(theString[1::])

    buildString.append(theString[0])





toPrint = "Hello Everyone!"
buildString = []   
recursiveMessage(toPrint)
print(parse(buildString))
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Under some conditions, `recursiveMessage` calls itself. So it is, indeed, recursive.

Comment: If at any point in time a function calls itself then it is consider recursive. This is the case in your example, so yes, it is recursive.

Comment: Thanks lurker, So am I right to think as long as the function has a base case to cancel out and it is simplifying itself its considered recursive?

Comment: so which is quicker recursion or iteration?

Comment: @PaulHashmi Recursion is usually slower and eats up more memory due to a new [call frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers) having to be created on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) each recursive call. If you know your recursive function will need to be run many times, iteration is the best route.

Comment: Ty Christian, I thought as much as well considering function calls eat clock cycles...Still pretty cool all the same :)

Comment: @Paul much better than your first attempt :)

Comment: You gonna hit that up arrow then Jon lol...And yeah really struggling with this. suppose thats what school is for though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this recursive?

If at any point in a function's execution it calls itself, then it is consider recursive. This happens in your example, so `recursiveMessage` is indeed recursive.

> so which is quicker recursion or iteration?

Recursion is usually much slower and consumes more space due to a new [stack frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack#Stack_and_frame_pointers) having to be created on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) each recursive call. If you know your recursive function will need to be run many times, iteration is the best route.

As an interesting side note, many compilers actually optimize a recursive function by rolling it out into a loop anyways.

Comment: @PaulHashmi Glad I help out :-)